# Where can I find any examples how to use TZipFile in C++ Builder

Tags: zip, c++builder

I'm trying to read a file from a `*.zip` to `TMemoryStream`:

```
String fName = "myInfo.txt";
std::auto_ptr<TMemoryStream> input(new TMemoryStream);
std::auto_ptr<TStringList> sFile(new TStringList);
std::auto_ptr<TZipFile> zip(new TZipFile());
TZipHeader fHeader;
zip->Open(file, zmRead);
zip->Read(fName, input.get(), fHeader);
...
```

but I get an error:

> E2285 Could not find a match for 'TZipFile::Read(UnicodeString,TMemoryStream *,TZipHeader)'

I am an amateur programmer, and I would really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, Google does not find an answer in this topic.

What am I doing wrong?

I was looking for examples of using TZipFile.Read for C++Builder.

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Read

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Zip.TZipFile.Read), the `Stream` parameter is an output parameter, not an input parameter. `Read()` will create its own stream object and return back a pointer to it.

The parameter is a non-const reference to a `TStream*` variable, and a non-const reference can't bind to a temporary, so you can't pass in the temporary returned by `auto_ptr::get()`. You will have to  pass in an actual non-auto raw `TStream*` variable, and then construct the `auto_ptr` from that raw pointer, eg:

```
String fName = "myInfo.txt";

std::auto_ptr<TZipFile> zip(new TZipFile);
zip->Open(file, zmRead);

TStream* pStream = NULL;
TZipHeader fHeader;
zip->Read(fName, pStream, fHeader);
std::auto_ptr<TStream> input(pStream);

std::auto_ptr<TStringList> sFile(new TStringList);
sFile->LoadFromStream(input.get());
...
```

Comment: I tryed this code but "input" is not recive any data. It's empty.

Comment: My bad, I put the wrong filename in the `Open()` call. I have fixed that.

Comment: It is not a problem with file name.

Comment: @André there is no *functional* difference between the code I showed in my answer vs the "working" code you have now posted in your own answer. Except that I'm still using `auto_ptr` to free the stream, and you have abandoned that. But as far as the code calling `Read()` is concerned, the two codes are *functionally* identical.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked. The error was in the TStream declaration.
Thank you very much for help.
And here is the code that works.

```
String file = "myZipFile.zip";
String fName = "myFile.txt";
std::auto_ptr<TStringList> sFile(new TStringList);
std::auto_ptr<TZipFile> zip(new TZipFile());
zip->Open(file, zmRead);

TStream *fStream = NULL;
TZipHeader fHeader;

zip->Read(fName, fStream, fHeader);

sFile->LoadFromStream(fStream, TEncoding::GetEncoding(65001));
zip->Close();
...
```

I am extremely grateful for your help

Comment: `TEncoding::GetEncoding(65001)` should be `TEncoding::UTF8` instead. And you need to `delete` the  `TStream` object when you are done using it (which `auto_ptr` can do for you).

Comment: These codes are not identical. With auto_ptr you create an 'input; stream, which I don't use. In that case, I don't have to delete it.
UTF8 has a code page 65001 so the effect is the same.

Comment: I said they were *functionally* identical. In my example, the `pStream` pointer and the `input` auto_ptr are pointing at the same `TStream` object. In your code, you originally used an `auto_ptr` but you weren't using it correctly,and now you've abandoned it, creating a memory leak if you don't `delete` the `TStream` yourself.

Comment: Also, `TEncoding::GetEncoding()` returns a poo get to a new `TEncoding` object that you must `delete` when you are done using it, otherwise it is leaked. Whereas `TEncoding::UTF8` returns a pointer to a singleton `TEncoding` object that the RTL owns and will free for you during program exit.